# Return partial view within view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view `Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Add</h2>

<p>Begin building a question set by clicking the button below.</p>
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Product", "Add")'" />
```

Which calls the Product action within my AddController:

```
public ActionResult Product()
{
   ViewBag.Partial = true;
   return PartialView("Product");
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

When a user loads the page the content from my partial view (`Product.cshtml`) is hidden, however when they click the "Create" button which calls the `Product` action in my `AddController` I want to then load the `Product.cshtml` partial view into my `Index.cshtml` so the latter still has its original content, but this time with the `Product.cshtml` injected into it.

At the moment, it's only returning the partial view and not both views.

Is this achievable in MVC?

Comment: Do you have a list of products that you would wish to show?
1 way would be to make use of an EditorTemplate for Product, thus Product.cshtml

Comment: The code you posted does not do that. It sends the user to the other view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, basically what you need is to get your `PartialView` through AJAX call and load it into your page. Easiest to do with jQuery

You can do it with simple JavaScript.

In buttons `onclick` put name of your loading function, like `onclick="partialLoad()"`

Put `div` with some `id` on your page, like `<div id="loadFrame"></div>`

Then your script:

```
function parialLoad() {
    $("#loadFrame").load("/Product");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be the following.

Move your Products.cshtml to the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates or DisplayTemplates directory

Have a ViewModel that you populate that contains a list of Products that you pass to and from your view.

Thus:

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ProductViewModel();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new ProductViewModel();
    }
    if (model.Products == null)
    {
        model.Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    model.Products.Add(new Product { Name = "Some Product", Amount = model.Products.Count + 1});

    return View(model);
}
```

**ProductViewModel.cs**

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model DynamicViewExample.Controllers.ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>Add</h2>


    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Products)

    <p>Begin building a question set by clicking the button below.</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
}
```

And finally, the DisplayTemplate
**Product.cshtml**

```
@model DynamicViewExample.Models.Product
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Amount)
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Amount)
</div>
```

The reason I had to include the HiddenFor properties, was to enable the Products collection to populate otherwise you would get an empty collection all the time.

Again, this was a display template, that would return the following result

> ### Add
>
> Some Product 1
>   Some Product 2
>   Some Product 3
>   Some Product 4
>   Some Product 5
>   Begin building a question set by clicking the button below.

I hope this guides you into the direction you are wishing to go

Good Luck
Gawie Schneider